# Using CanCan with user_role table in rails3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, cancan

I have user_role table like this:

```
user_role_id (pk)
name (e.g admin)
access_one
access_two
acccess_three
```

and user_table with columns like:

```
user_id (pk)
user_role_id (fk)
username
password
```

I have view to create above users_roles through admin panel.
Then how can I use the named roles ? so that I can get benefit of [Role Inheritance](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Separate-Role-Model) in cancan & also I wish that list of rolenames should remain sync with database.

Further,
I wish to set access in `ability.rb` based on the access_one,access_two,etc. defined in user_role table.so,how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The best place to look is

[Cancan-ability](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/checking-abilities)

Cancan has a very nice documentation. Just going through it would be quite helpful.

EDIT:

```
      user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
        if user.admin?
          can :manage, :all
        elsif user.student?
          can :manage, [Book, Copies]
          can :manage, Theme
        else  
          can :read, :all
        end

      end
```

you can use can and cannot to take care of permissions. Like

```
can :manage, Model_name, Action_name
```

This will make sure that a specific model is taken into consideration with privileges to speified view.

Comment: I have gone through it,just I can't find how to use database to define access in `ability` model